# How can I view the changes in an SVN repository done by a particular user?

Tags: svn

Basically I want svn status -u to display only the files changed by a particular user since so that I can update only those.

Answer (score 2):

This type of analysis/reporting question is fairly straightforward in PowerShell (Windows only, of course). Start with this workhorse to convert svn log data to PowerShell objects:

```
Function Get-SvnLogData()
{
    ([xml](svn log -v --xml)).log.logentry | % {
        $nestedEntry = $_
        $_.paths.path | % {
            $path = $_
            $nestedEntry | Select-Object -Property `
                Author, `
                @{n='Revision'; e={([int]$_.Revision)}}, `
                @{n='Date';     e={Get-Date $_.Date  }}, `
                @{n='Action';   e={$path.action      }}, `
                @{n='Path';     e={$path.InnerText   }}`
        }
    }
}
```

Once the log is converted to objects, PowerShell's native cmdlets provide countless ways to massage the data. Here are just a couple possibilities to address the question at hand:

**Question 1: when was each file touched by author x?**

Show files committed by a particular author;
a file may appear multiple times (includes each time author touched file).

```
Get-SvnLogData |
where { $_.Author -eq 'smith' } |
select Revision,Date,Path | 
sort -property `
    @{ Expression="Path";     Descending=$false }, `
    @{ Expression="Revision"; Descending=$true  } |
Format-Table -AutoSize
# To sort by latest changes instead of by file,
# swap Path and Revision properties in sort statement.
```

**Question 2: when was the last time each file was touched by author x (and incidentally how many times was it touched)?**

Show files committed by a particular author;
each file appears just once with a count of touches and last touched date.

```
Get-SvnLogData |
where { $_.Author -eq 'smith' } |
group Path |
select `
    @{ n='Last Touched'; e= {@($_.group | sort date -Descending)[0].date} }, `
    @{ n='NumberOfTimesTouched'; e={$_.count} }, `
    name |
sort name | Format-Table -AutoSize
# To sort by latest changes instead of by file change last line to:
# sort date | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the example below, using the [svn log command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) with username, 'jainendra':

```
svn log | sed -n '/jainendra/,/-----$/ p'
```

here *sed* is a linux command.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
svn log --username <username>
```

command

Also, you can add the --limit arg so you don't get your screen filled with commits. This is something you can't easily achieve when sed'ing the output of svn for a username.

```
svn log --username ankit --limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the output of `svn log` (or `svn status`) to search only for that user's entries.

If you use `svn log --xml`, you can execute an XPath query against the results or apply an XSLT to perform this filtering, capturing all `<logentry>` nodes with a `<author>` node containing the desired username.